# Do GCP ML Engine online predictions support API keys?

Tags: google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm attempting to make online predictions using  `https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project>/models/<model>/versions/<version>:predict?key=<mykey>`

I created a service account with full ML Engine Admin access, then generated an unrestricted API key. Many of Google's online docs mention `?key=` as a valid auth method for their APIs. Can anyone confirm that this is supported by ML Engine today?

I was able to make the same request using `Authorization: Bearer <access token>` with my own personal access token, but I do not want to do that. Additionally, the request will ultimately be made via PHP, and the client libraries for PHP currently do not support ML Engine yet.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I found a separate library specifically for auth: https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-php. I'd still like to know if ?key= is supported, though. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported by CMLE Online Prediction.
There is a list of supported GCP services here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys

Comment: Thank you! Idk why this was so hard for me to find. :(